# openshift private docker registry Unable to push [docker-maven-plugin]

Tags: maven, docker, openshift-origin

i have a little problem with my docker-registry on openshift-origin installation.

i have created a docker-registry pods :

```
 oc get pods
    NAME                            READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
    docker-registry-3-h46uj         1/1       Running   0          14m
```

created a route :

```
oc get routes
docker-registry docker-registry.vagrant.f8 docker-registry
```

created a service :

```
oc get service
docker-registry 172.30.14.216 <none> 5000/TCP docker-registry=default 3d
```

Master of Openshift is on 10.0.2.235 with a single node, now i have created a spring-boot application where i use a maven-plugin-docker to build and push image.

When i run locally (on master machine) maven push work fine, but i have some problem if i run maven push from another machine, during maven push obtain:

```
[INFO] DOCKER> ... The push refers to a repository [docker-registry.vagrant.f8/fabric8/springboot-webmvc] (len: 1)
[INFO] DOCKER> ... Sending image list
[ERROR] DOCKER> Error: Status 503 trying to push repository fabric8/springboot-webmvc:
```

and

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.jolokia:docker-maven-plugin:0.13.8:push (default-cli) on project springboot-webmvc: Unable to push 'fabric8/springboot-webmvc:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT' from registry 'docker-registry.vagrant.f8' -> [Help 1]
```

I did not understand what is the correct docker-registry host,

- is the pod ip ?
- is the service ip ?
- is the hostname of route?

The plugin's configuration in the pom.xml is this:

```
 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jolokia</groupId>
                <artifactId>docker-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${docker.maven.plugin.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                 <authConfig>
                    <username></username>
                    <password></password>
                 </authConfig>
                    <images>
                        <image>
                            <name>${docker.image}</name>
                            <build>
                                <from>${docker.from}</from>
                                <assembly>
                                    <basedir>/app</basedir>
                                    <descriptorRef>artifact</descriptorRef>
                                </assembly>
                                <env>
                                    <JAVA_APP_JAR>${project.build.finalName}.jar</JAVA_APP_JAR>
                                </env>
                            </build>
                        </image>
                    </images>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

and to push in my private docker registry i use this propertie :

```
<docker.push.registry>docker-registry.vagrant.f8</docker.push.registry>
```

thanks all for any help

Answer (score 0):

So for route to work you will need a router setup and a DNS that will resolve to the router IP. That said, I have not setup a registry app as application within openshift.